# Go back to previous page in php where previous page url should taken from the firefox address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I have created an application to check the malicious url in the web page. In that i have created a page call error.php which will get open when the user click the malicious link in the web page. i want to go back to the previous page i.e., the page with malicious content which already loaded in the user browser.

eg: I want to go to the page /localhost/url/page1.php?url=www.google.com after pressing button in the error.php page.

I wrote my application in php.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Can we see what code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways:

1. use javascript to get the link via `document.referrer`
2. parse a referrer to the url, something like www.mysite.com/check.php?referrer=www.google.com. Then get the referrer via `$_GET['referrer']` and echo it to the link.

Answer (score 0):

In the error.php write a javascript function on clicking the button

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function goback()
 {
 window.history.back()
 }
 </script>
```